# how can i use async await in regular order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

when i act onPress onPress={() => Login()} function

first of all, i want to get token by using signInWithKakao function,
second of all, right after i got token, if i have token, i want to dispatch profile by using
kakaoprofile function

if i use my code when i act onPress, this error occure

```
  token is not defined
```

I think it is because signInWithKakao is not recognized because it is in the Login function.

how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```js
import {
  getProfile as getKakaoProfile,
  login,
} from '@react-native-seoul/kakao-login';

const Kakao = () => {

  const [result, setResult] = useState('');

  const Login = () => {

    const signInWithKakao = async() => {
      const token = await login();
      setResult(JSON.stringify(token));
    };

    if (token) {
      const kakaoprofile = async() => {
        const profile = await getKakaoProfile();
        // console.log("profile:",profile);
        dispatch({
          type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
          data: profile
        })
      };
    }
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <LoginButton onPress = {() => Login()}>
        <Label>카카오 로그인</Label>
      </LoginButton>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Kakao;
```

Comment: What is the problem right now? What is the error?

Comment: @Konstantin i updated my post for error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create another function. let's say handleOrder and make it async and then put all your awaits there.

```js
const Login = () => {
  handleInOrder()
}

async function handleInOrder() {
try{
  const token = await getKakaoProfile()
  if(token){
   let data = await nextInOrder(token)
   //do a dispatch
   }
} catch(err){
  // handle the error
}
}
```

Let me know,if you need any help